# Create java module inside android project in IntelliJ Idea

Tags: java, android, intellij-idea

I'm using IntelliJ Idea Ultimate 14.1.4

I'm following a tutorial about TDD on android, one of the steps is to create an independent non-android java module, I tried to do that but it has no build.gradle file.
I'm just trying file -> new -> module -> Java -> Java EE (changing module SDK to Java JDK) -> name it -> finish.

In android studio one does: File -> New Module -> Java Library -> name it -> finish. And it has its build.gradle.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: If my response has answered your question, you should click to accept it as the answer.  Welcome to the site!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A Java module in IntelliJ IDEA is not inherently a Gradle module - this is something that Android Studio does (as for why, I believe it's just that Google decided it should be that way, but don't quote me on that).

If you want a Gradle-based Java module in IntelliJ IDEA, you need to have the Gradle plugin installed, and then select 'Gradle' instead of 'Java' within the 'New Module' menu.

Please note that you can make a Gradle project/module without any Java at all - Java is just one of the plugins you can use within Gradle!  To quote [wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gradle):

> The initial plugins are primarily focused around Java, Groovy and
>   Scala development and deployment, but more languages and project
>   workflows are on the roadmap.